# javascript If Variable(s) is True

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding how True/False works in Javascript or not.
In my Jquery script below I'm declaring 6 variables as false.
If the regex validation conditions are good, then I redeclare the variable(s) to true.
On the bottom is a simple alert() to tell me when all variables are true.

The validation conditions are working (removing/adding classes), but the alert does not show up.  That's why I'm not sure if I'm messing up the true/false part or not.

```
$('#password1').keyup(function() {
var checkLength = false;
var checkLetter = false;
var checkCaps = false;
var checkNum = false;
var checkSymbol = false;
var checkSpace = false;

var pswd = $(this).val();


//validate the length
if(pswd.length < 6 ){ 
 $('#length').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid'); 
}else{ 
 $('#length').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid'); 
 checkLength = true; 
}

//validate letter
if(pswd.match(/[A-Za-z]/)){ 
 $('#letter').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid'); 
}else{ 
 $('#letter').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid'); 
 checkLetter = true; 
}

//validate capital letter
if(pswd.match(/[A-Z]/)){ 
 $('#capital').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid'); 
}else{ 
 $('#capital').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid'); 
 checkCaps = true; 
}

//validate number
if(pswd.match(/\d/)){ 
 $('#number').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid'); 
}else{ 
 $('#number').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid'); 
 checkNum = true; 
}   

//validate symbols
if(pswd.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/)){ 
 $('#symbol').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid'); 
}else{ 
 $('#symbol').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid'); 
 checkSymbol = true; 
}   

//validate no spaces
if(pswd.match(/\s/)){ 
 $('#spaces').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid'); 
}else{ 
 $('#spaces').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid'); 
 checkSpace = true; 
}

// here is where I'm concerned I'm wrong
if(checkLength == true && checkLetter == true && checkCaps == true && checkNum == true && checkSymbol == true && checkSpace == true){ 
    alert("All good"); 
}

});
```

Would someone double check me?

Comment: *Never* write `== true`. It is almost always superfluous, and when it is not, your script needs refactoring.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: I guess you just got some the conditions wrong. For example, if the password contains any letter from `a` to `z`, you don't set `checkLetter` to `true`. `.match` returns `null` if it **does not** match.

Comment: You might try test() over match() for your regex checks. Test gives you a true/false response where match() returns an array

Comment: @scrappedcola What is `test()`? I can't recall a method on the String-Object with such a name...

Comment: @coffemonitor I prepared a fiddle for you that works.

Comment: @coffemonitor - test is used like this: /[A-Z]/.test(pswd). It is a regular expression method that  returns a true/false value rather than the matches (which you don't seem to need) http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev3.shtml

Comment: @scrappedcola Ah, well, another lection learned. However, if it has no speedbonus, there is no benefit since it doesn't matter what is returned as long as it's truthy/falsy which is also the case for `.match()`. And (for me) match somehow has a more convenient style with the string first and the regex as argument.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At first, there is no need to write `checkLength == true`, `checkLength` is enough since they are all boolean variables.

Second, in some of your conditions you assign class `invalid` but set the var to true, while in others you do it vice versa. Every `check... = true` should be in the same branch with `class = valid`. 
Also, personally, I would adapt the validity conditions, to have all positive events either in the `if` or in the `else` branch, but not mixed like you do at the moment. 
Lastly, I always try to avoid duplicate code. There are a lot of places you could refactor, but you could start easy with setting the classes in a separate function.

See it working **[in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/FGVma/)**.

```js
$('#password1').keyup(function() {
  var checkLength = false;
  var checkLetter = false;
  var checkCaps = false;
  var checkNum = false;
  var checkSymbol = false;
  var checkSpace = false;

  var pswd = $(this).val();


  //validate the length
  // reverse the condition, to have the valid state in the if branch as well
  if(pswd.length >= 6 ){ 
   setValid('#length'); 
   checkLength = true; 
  }else{ 
   setInvalid('#length');  
  }

  //validate letter
  if(pswd.match(/[A-Za-z]/)){
   setValid('#letter'); 
   checkLetter = true; 
  }else{ 
   setInvalid('#letter'); 
  }

  //validate capital letter
  if(pswd.match(/[A-Z]/)){ 
   setValid('#capital');
   checkCaps = true; 
  }else{ 
   setInvalid('#capital'); 
  }

  //validate number
  if(pswd.match(/\d/)){ 
   setValid('#number');
   checkNum = true;  
  }else{ 
   setInvalid('#number'); 
  }   

  //validate symbols
  if(pswd.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/)){ 
   setValid('#symbol'); 
   checkSymbol = true; 
  }else{ 
   setInvalid('#symbol'); 
  }   

  //validate no spaces
  if(!pswd.match(/\s/)){
   setValid('#spaces'); 
   checkSpace = true;  
  }else{ 
   setInvalid('#spaces'); 
  }

  function setValid(e){$(e).removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid')} 
  function setInvalid(e){$(e).removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid')} 

  if(checkLength && checkLetter && checkCaps && checkNum && checkSymbol && checkSpace){ 
  alert("All good"); 
  }
  console.log("keyup");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="password1" type="text">
```

Comment: That last point you edited in is incorrect. The test is for symbols, not for alphanumeric characters at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 2):

All of these have `check* = true` in the wrong place:

```
//validate letter
if(pswd.match(/[A-Za-z]/)){ 
 $('#letter').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid'); 
}else{ 
 $('#letter').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid'); 
 checkLetter = true; 
}

//validate capital letter
if(pswd.match(/[A-Z]/)){ 
 $('#capital').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid'); 
}else{ 
 $('#capital').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid'); 
 checkCaps = true; 
}

//validate number
if(pswd.match(/\d/)){ 
 $('#number').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid'); 
}else{ 
 $('#number').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid'); 
 checkNum = true; 
}   

//validate symbols
if(pswd.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/)){ 
 $('#symbol').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid'); 
}else{ 
 $('#symbol').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid'); 
 checkSymbol = true; 
}
```

Insert the statements in the block following the `if` (where they are deemed valid) as opposed to in the `else` (where they are deemed invalid):

```
//validate letter
if(pswd.match(/[A-Za-z]/)){ 
 $('#letter').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid'); 
 checkLetter = true; 
}else{ 
 $('#letter').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid'); 
}

//validate capital letter
if(pswd.match(/[A-Z]/)){ 
 $('#capital').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid'); 
 checkCaps = true; 
}else{ 
 $('#capital').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid'); 
}

//validate number
if(pswd.match(/\d/)){ 
 $('#number').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid'); 
}else{ 
 $('#number').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid'); 
 checkNum = true; 
}   

//validate symbols
if(pswd.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/)){ 
 $('#symbol').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid'); 
 checkSymbol = true; 
}else{ 
 $('#symbol').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid'); 
}
```

And, although there are better ways of writing validation, this is a similar, yet more concise version of your snippet:

```
$("#password1").keyup(function() {
    var pswd = $(this).val();
    var checkLength = pswd.length >= 6;
    var checkLetter = /[A-Za-z]/.test(pswd);
    var checkCaps   = /[A-Z]/.test(pswd);
    var checkNum    = /\d/.test(pswd);
    var checkSymbol = /[^A-Za-z0-9]/.test(pswd);
    var checkSpace  = !/\s/.test(pswd);

    $("#length") .removeClass("valid invalid").addClass(checkLength ? "valid" : "invalid");
    $("#letter") .removeClass("valid invalid").addClass(checkLetter ? "valid" : "invalid");
    $("#capital").removeClass("valid invalid").addClass(checkCaps   ? "valid" : "invalid");
    $("#number") .removeClass("valid invalid").addClass(checkNum    ? "valid" : "invalid");
    $("#symbol") .removeClass("valid invalid").addClass(checkSymbol ? "valid" : "invalid");
    $("#spaces") .removeClass("valid invalid").addClass(checkSpace  ? "valid" : "invalid");

    if(checkLength && checkLetter && checkCaps && checkNum && checkSymbol && checkSpace) {
        alert("All good");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, it seems that your assignments are valid statements. Whether or not they are getting set the way you want is a different matter.

It is most likely that one of the flags is not being set the way you want it to be set. To check this, you could alert each of your flags (checkCaps, etc) to confirm that each value is set the way you want. If all of the true/false is correct, then the issue would be in your final if statement.

As many people have suggested, removing the `== true` is a good idea. Since Javascript is dynamically typed, there is a *slight* possibility that it is not treating your flags as a boolean, but as something else.

If removing the `== true` does not work, you could check different pairs of flags to see which one makes the entire statement false.